# Laravel 5.5 : Not receiving password reset link mail

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, postman, reset-password

I am using hostgators/AWS smtp service. everything is good . my mail function is working great as i am able to send all my forms data on my website. but when i am trying to reset password (forgot password?) ...when i click send reset link it is showing that link has been sent (please check screenshot ) .. but i am not getting any mail. i have tried to send mails to different registered users but not getting that reset link . 
i have created this login system using php artisan make:auth .

If I tested with POSTMAN or any API client it is working but once I implemented it with the application it is not working.

more details will be provided if needed.[image]

Comment: Check if record exists is your password_reset table. Also do check your mail spam box

Comment: there is a entry with token and email and spam also checked .

Comment: Make sure your env and mail.php file is configured properly.

Comment: After modifying your .env file, execute: `php artisan config:cache`. That did it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .env file add new variable called `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=your_smtp_from_mail_id` . you have to set MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS to valid smtp from_mail email id. sometimes in .env file this variable doesn't exist. if it is not set manually ;   when sending mail it is picking up a default mail id which is `hello@example.com`.
please have look here config/mail.php

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

i think this should work !

This worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is from the mail configuration on .env file.
Check mail configuration in .env file, also read laravel.log

Comment: i have a contact form and other forms also in my site. but they are sending mail and i am receiving it. but only password reset mail i am not receiving.

Answer (score 0):

check your spam. If your are using localhost then probably the email are in spam folder.